# getting wrong data when I use inner join keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with MySQL query, I want to get all rows that associate with same FK.
code is :

```
$idad =(int)$_GET['id'];// I am using this to get the id of ad from the url of page
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ads INNER JOIN cars ON cars.ad_id="'.$idad.'"
                 INNER JOIN address ON address.ad_id="'.$idad.'" ';
```

***I got the wrong result for ads table only*** , it returns the wrong ad_id row. But for address and cars I got the correct row.

Comment: is cars and address ID same?

Comment: The SQL ON part is the condition that joins 2 tables, you are using it as the condition to select. Your SQL command should be `SELECT * FROM ads INNER JOIN cars ON cars.ad_id=ads.ad_id INNER JOIN address ON address.ad_id=ads.ad_id where ads.ad_id = $idad`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by editing the SQL query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ads  JOIN cars ON cars.ad_id="'.$idad.'" AND ads.ad_id="'.$idad.'"
              JOIN address ON address.ad_id="'.$idad.'" ';
```

and it worked fine now.

Comment: Except that you're still wide open to sql injection

Answer (score 2):

You have to map the ad_id with other table forgin key ad id.

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM ads 
       INNER JOIN cars ON cars.ad_id=ads.ad_id
       INNER JOIN address ON address.ad_id=ads.ad_id
       WHERE ads.ad_id = $idad
```

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting all from ads table but you have to use join for that.

```
$idad =(int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ads INNER JOIN cars ON cars.ad_id=address.ad_id
                 INNER JOIN address ON address.ad_id=ads.ad_id WHERE ad_id=$idad';
```